# Can't display a single Image in android

Tags: android, imageview, ram

Im trying to make a game, but i'm consistently running out of memory when loading imageviews. I used functions i found on a tutorial to scale images down before actually loading them, but when i try to load a single image with the resolution of the screen, i run out of RAM.
I deleted everything else, so an app remained, which actually doesn't do anything else than loading one image. Still crashes. How can i resolve this problem?
The remainings of the code:

```
package com.example.sert.cannotshowanimage;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    ImageView img;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par;
    img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sf, (int) (width), (int) (height)));
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}

thanks for help

Comment: Sometimes image loading causes memory exception. So instead loading directly use some kind of library like picasso, etc

Comment: it semms that the emulator is buggy, if i run the app on my phone instead of the emulator it works (and uses "just" 40MB. Still too much IMO, but at least it works)